# How to create Ruby Tk radiobuttons in nested loops

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

Using Ruby Tk, I'm wanting to create sets of radio buttons in nested loops:  an outer loop for devices (Foo, Bar, Baz), and inner loop for actions on each device (Start, Stop, Pause, Nuke).

Current code:

```
require 'tk'

device_names = %w/Foo Bar Baz/
action_names = %w/Start Pause Stop Nuke/

button_variables = Array.new(device_names.size)

root = TkRoot.new

foo = bar = nil

device_names.each_with_index do |device_name, i|
  TkLabel.new(root) do
    text device_name
    pack {}
  end
  action_names.each_with_index do |action_name, j|
    TkRadiobutton.new(root) do
      text action_name
      value j
      variable button_variables[i]
      pack {}
    end
  end
end

Tk.mainloop
```

This produces the 12 radiobuttons, but when I click on any of the 4 Pause buttons, for example, all 4 Pause buttons are set.

Other variations of the code produce the 12 radiobuttons, but all as one set;  i.e., only one of the 12 is set at any given time.

What's needed to group these into 3 sets of 4 radiobuttons?

(This code is pared down from a much larger application, which is why it does not make much sense symantically.)

Comment: (NB: I didn't go look at the Tk* interface.) I don't see where '```button_variables```' are set? It seems possible that's a part of the problem...

Comment: Setting each `button_variables[i]` did not change the  behavior.

Comment: And thanks, Derrell.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed as `variable` is the name of a *global* variable.

The outer loop needs to dynamically define an instance variable, via `instance_variable_set`:

This code works:

```
require 'tk'

device_names = %w/Foo Bar Baz/
action_names = %w/Start Pause Stop Nuke/

root = TkRoot.new

device_names.each do |device_name|
  TkLabel.new(root) do
    text device_name
    pack {}
  end
  instance_variable_set("@#{device_name}", nil)
  action_names.each do |action_name|
    TkRadiobutton.new(root) do
      text action_name
      value action_name
      variable device_name
      pack {}
    end
  end
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Comment: Since you say that this code works, please accept your own answer. This accords with StackOverflow standard practice.